# Best matching point (subtract 2 arrays)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math

How can I implement the following equation (in context of image manipulation) in Python? The best matching point (by subtracting 2 arrays). Where `x is (3, 1288)` and `m is (3,10)`.

I tried implementing it in the following way, but it didn't work.

```py
for matX in matM.T:
    b.append(np.argmin([np.sum((matX - matM)**2) for i in matX]))`
```

[image]

Comment: Question is a bit vague... Can you elaborate more? Even a reference for the equation would be enough.

Comment: by "Where x is (3, 1288) and m is (3,10)" you mean shape? Also, please provide a small data example you want to work with and the desired result